# Which stemming algorithm should I use?

Tags: nlp, porter-stemmer

We are developing a vertical search engine as our BTech project. We want to use a stemmer to convert words on webpages to their root words. We tried using Porter Stemmer but it is not giving expected outcome.

Porter Stemmer falsely converts e.g.

```
1. goes -> goe
2. ponies -> poni
3. happily -> happili
```

So can anybody suggest which algorithm should we use?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this in the past. Porter Stemmer does an excellent job of allowing word comparisons, but it can't be used for display.  My basic algorithm was:

1. Crawl pages and run their contents through Porter Stemmer to store the root words.
2. Take user input and run that through Porter Stemmer to get the root of user input.
3. Compare crawled root words to user input root words (in my case with a dictionary of stop words excluded)
4. Generate the results page for display and run it through a presentation layer which bolded all of the words which had a matching root word in the user's query.

It looks like you're most of the way there - it's just the presentation bit that needs some extra work.

*Update:* just to clarify what I mean here, imagine Porter stemmer didn't produce readable stems, but instead produced numeric stem IDs (e.g. Goes -> 3749). The algorithm would still work, but you'd still have to remap root words to full words for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a Stemmer, you need a [Lemmatizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation).
[Morpha](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/johnca/morph.html) is a really good lemmatizer.
The [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) tools come with a java port of morpha if that is easier for you to use.